# Cannot log in gcloud SDK using the non google account

Tags: gcloud

I associated with my other email (mymail@cn.waha.com) with my google account (jinchihe@gmail.com).
When I try to run the `gcloud auth login mymail@cn.waha.com`, open a web browser, and by default that's gmail and I selected the `Use another account` to input my other email and password, and then still show `Google Cloud Sdk wants to access your Google Account jinchihe@gmail.com`, I click `Allow` but screen shows

```
ERROR: (gcloud.auth.login) You attempted to log in as account [mymail@cn.waha.com] but the received credentials were for account [jinchihe@gmail.com].

Please check that your browser is logged in as account [mymail@cn.waha.com] and that you are using the correct browser profile.
```

Seems only can logged in by google account? How can I log in with my mymail@cn.waha.com, I need show mymail@cn.waha.com in gcloud info so pass authentication. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can sign in using one of the following identities:

- Google account
- Service account
- Google group G Suite domain account

If your domain is part of the Google G suite domain then you should be able to log in, using third party domains (such a Hotmail, yahoo, etc) won't let you*. You state that you were able to "log in" into your account through the browser and "allow" the permission. After that you should see a code (random string of text) that you would have to copy and paste into the shell console before continuing the authentication.

*note: you can create a Google Account using a third party email domain, just go to the [Create your Coogle Account](https://accounts.google.com/signup/v2/webcreateaccount?flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=SignUp) page and click on **"Use my current email address instead"** to introduce your personal email (in your case "mymail@cn.waha.com").

Also, according to the error message, you are running the command with "mymail@cn.waha.com" but on the browser you are logging in with "jinchihe@gmail.com" account.

Comment: Thanks for the replying. Yes, I just want to log in using the third party domains, instead of gamil...

Comment: I'm afraid that's not possible, since Google needs to confirm your identity and cannot do it if you don't login using an email under Google domain.

Comment: So Google accounts need to be either gmail accounts or gsuite accounts? I thought it was possible to create a non-gmail, non-gsuite Google account? Doesn't it just verify your identity by sending you an email at that address?

Comment: @jeremy-lewi is mostly correct. You may associate a non-Google email address with a Google identity (without creating an associated Gmail account). At the Google signup page select "Use my current email address". This Google identity may then be associated with GCP projects. I strongly recommend you use a different password for this "wrapped" account. https://accounts.google.com/signup/v2/webcreateaccount?flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=SignUp

Comment: @DazWilkin thank you for the clarification!, i will update my answer accordingly.